# Generating the Fibonacci Sequence in Matlab using recursive function NOT using any loop

Tags: matlab, function, recursion, fibonacci

I am trying to write a recursive matlab function that takes one argument and generates the fibonacci sequence up to n. The codes I have found everywhere either output only the n-th term or use loops to output the whole sequence. Now I am not allowed to use any kind of loops, just pure recursive function. I will highly appreciate if anyone can share his/her thoughts. Thanks in advance.
I am copying the code that gives the n-th term only for convenience.

```
function f = fibor(n)
    if n == 1 || n == 2
        f = 1;
    else
        f = fibor(n-1) + fibor(n-2);
    end
end
```

Comment: Downvoting because I think the question is not useful. As for the solution, have two functions `fibor_with_output` and `fibor_only_calculate`, then change the recursive part as `f = fibor_with_output(n-1) + fibor_only_calculate(n-2);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try the code below, which saves the outputs

```
function f = fibor(n)
    if n <= 2
        f = ones(1,n);
    else
        u = fibor(n-1);
        f = [u,sum(u(end-1:end))];
    end
end
```

which gives

```
>> fibor(5)
ans =

   1   1   2   3   5

>> fibor(10)
ans =

    1    1    2    3    5    8   13   21   34   55
```